# Formatting results of get-item differently

Tags: powershell

I have registry key that I need to retrieve the name of the strings from.
For example:  `HKLM:\Software\MyRegKey` has four string values in it.  String A, String B, String C, and String D.  I use the following Powershell to gather this information

```
Get-Item -Path HKLM:\Software\MyRegKey | select-object -expandproperty`
property
```

The above will return the following:

```
A
B
C
D
```

What I need to do is format that output differently.  Simply put, I need it to return just one value and then I need to put that into a foreach statement to iterate through and return the rest of the values.

Is this possible?

```
Get-Item -Path HKLM:\Software\MyRegKey | select-object -expandproperty`
property

Get-Item -Path HKLM:\Software\MyRegKey | select-object -expandproperty`
property
```

The above will return the following:

```
A
B
C
D
```

Desired output:

```
A
```

Then run a foreach statement to gather each value individually.

Comment: Due to bad formatting it's unclear if `Get-Item -Path HKLM:\Software\MyRegKey` returns an array you simply could pipe to a `ForEach-Object`

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple values in a string like this:

```
$MyRegKey = "A B C D"
$MyRegKey.Count
1
```

And you want to step through them, you can split on the 'space' character like this.

```
$MyRegKey = $MyRegKey.Split()
$MyRegKey.Count
4
```

This gives you something you can iterate through using the `For-EachObject` cmdlet.

```
$MyRegKey
A
B
C
D
```

**Update**

Imagine making a new regkey like this:

```
New-Item HKCU:\Software\MyRegKey 
New-ItemProperty -Path HKCU:\Software\MyRegKey -Name MyRegValue -PropertyType String -Value "A B C D"
```

This will create the following key:

[image]

I can retrieve its value with the following code:

```
$MyRegKey = Get-ItemProperty -Path HKCU:\Software\MyRegKey -Name MyRegValue
$MyRegKey.MyRegValue.Split()
A
B
C
D
```

We can iterate through the values like this:

```
MyRegKey.MyRegValue.Split() | ForEach-Object { "Property $i of MyRegKey = $_" ;$i++}
Property 0 of MyRegKey = A
Property 1 of MyRegKey = B
Property 2 of MyRegKey = C
Property 3 of MyRegKey = D
```

### Final Update

We can make the following regkeys quickly with this code:

```
'A','B','C','D' | % {
New-ItemProperty -Path HKCU:\Software\MyRegKey -Name $_ -PropertyType String -Value "A B C D"
}
```

Giving us these values:

[image]

To act on these in a `ForEach-Object` loop, we can use the following code:

```
(Get-Item -Path HKCU:\Software\MyRegKey).Property | ForEach-Object { 
    Write-Host "The key $_ has a value of $((Get-ItemProperty HKCU:\Software\MyRegKey -Name $_).$_)"
}
```

This gives the following output:

```
The key A has a value of A B C D
The key B has a value of A B C D
The key C has a value of A B C D
The key D has a value of A B C D
```

Comment: Ok, so I came up with this code:  `$myregkey = get-item -path HKLM:\Software\MyRegkey | select-object - expandproperty property  $MyRegKey = $MyRegkey.split()`  However, I don't think that is right.  Apologies for the one line of code, the comments will not let me hit Enter for a new line.  When I hit enter here, it saves the edit.

Comment: Can you give an exact example of what the key's value looks like, and then how you want to access the data instead?  I think you might need to reword your question, it's kind of hard to follow now :(

Comment: Sure I can try.  So in your example, you're retrieving the values of the string.  I don't want to do that.  I just want to retrieve the strings in the registry key MyRegKey.  ![Valid XHTML](https://i.imgur.com/d0H7Stv.png)  You can see in the screenshot the strings are what I am returning with `get-item -Path HKLM:\Software\MyRegKey | select-object -expandproperty property`  That code works to return the correct data, but like I mentioned, it's returned as one block of data.  I need it returned individually, and then pass it into a foreach statement.

Comment: A screenshot is worth a thousand words!  I understand now :)  Checkout my final update

Comment: It looks like this is not exactly what I was looking for.  Do you see how in your final update you're returning the values of A, B, C, and D?  I don't want to do that.  I just want to return A, B, C, and D as individual objects.  If you view the following VB Script https://pastebin.com/bB9g9yuB and run that, you will see how it returns the names in the key as A, B, C, and D individually.  PowerShell returns it as one big block of A, B, C and D.  Does that make sense?

Comment: I finally got it!  I just can't explain it.  Here is what works.  `$key = "SOFTWARE\MyRegKey"
$type = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive]::LocalMachine
$regKey = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey($type, $Srv)
$regKey = $regKey.OpenSubKey($key)

Foreach($val in $regKey.GetValueNames()){$val}`  If you just type $val, you will notice it only has one value in it.  That is perfect and how I need it.  The foreach loop gives me all values.  Why `get-item -Path HKLM:\Software\MyRegKey | select-object -expandproperty property treats it differently, I do not know.

Answer (score 0):

The following is what I ended up with and seems to be working as the variable `$i` contains just one value.  `$t = get-item -Path HKLM:\Software\MyRegKey | select-object -expandproperty property
foreach($i in $t){$i}`  This worked by changing the way I was doing the foreach loop.  I was incorrectly passing in the variable into a foreach loop.